# Add properties to Firebase analytics event

Tags: firebase-analytics

We are using Firebase Analytics now to log some of the events in our game. Since we missed recording some of the attributes along with these events, I was wondering if it is possible to add those attributes to already recorded events.

Answer (score 0):

If you export to big query you will be able to add them in big query,but it won't be reflected in the firebase dashboard, instead you could build your own custom dashboard with Google Data Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way within Firebase Analytics to go back and add params to events that have already been logged.  Newly logged events will get new params that you define but already-logged events will never get them.